# Adding control to ASP.NET with jQuery

Tags: asp.net, jquery, vb.net

I'm trying to add control to the ASP.NET page. Controls are added successfully but can't access from code behind. In the sample below, when Button1 is clicked, there's no element in "uploads" (type HttpFileCollection).

Here's my mark-up:

```
<%@ Page Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="add-remove-control.aspx.vb"
    Inherits="APIU.Web.add_remove_control" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>

    <script src="_Assets/scripts/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {

            var i = 1;
            //allow only 3 elements

            $('#add').click(function() {
                if (i < 4) {
                    var add_input = '<input type="file" id="' + 'dynamic:' + i + '" name="' + 'dynamic:' + i + '" />'
                    var add_link = '<a href="#" class="remove">Remove</a>'
                    $('body').append('<p>' + add_input + add_link + '</p>');
                    i++;
                }
            });

            $('.remove').live('click', function() {
                $(this).parent('p').remove();
                i--;
            });


        });
    </script>

</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <a href="#" id="add">Add</a>

        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" />
        <br />
        <p>
            &nbsp;</p>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Code behind:

```
Protected Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim uploads As HttpFileCollection
        uploads = HttpContext.Current.Request.Files

        Dim sfile As String


        For i As Integer = 0 To (uploads.Count - 1)

            If (uploads(i).ContentLength > 0) Then
                Dim c As String = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(uploads(i).FileName)

                Try
                    uploads(i).SaveAs("C:\UploadedUserFiles\" + c)

                    sfile += uploads(i).FileName & "<br/>"

                Catch Exp As Exception

                End Try

            End If

        Next i


    End Sub
```

Why there's no element in "uploads" (type HttpFileCollection)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason it doesn't show up server-side is here:

```
$('body').append('<p>' + add_input + add_link + '</p>');
```

This appends to the `<body>` element, which is most importantly *outside* the `<form>`...so the inputs you're using aren't included in the POST.  Append the elements to the `<form>` instead, like this:

```
$('form').append('<p>' + add_input + add_link + '</p>');
```

---

This is the same reason input elements inside a [`.dialog()`](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/) call don't get submitted in ASP.Net, again it's moved just before `</body>` and outside the `</form>`...you need a `.dialog().parent().appendTo('form')` for the same reason there.

Comment: I added a div like this         <div id="upload-contorl">
         </div> and I append the controls to it like this  $('#upload-contorl').append('<p>' + add_input + add_link + '</p>'); I can append the controls to the div but still the controls won't show up on the severside. If try to add the attribute runat="server" in jQuery, the mark-up will not get render and it throw error.

Comment: @Morron - No need for `runat="server"` that's a different deal.  Your form likely has the wrong encoding though, add this to your `<form>` tag: `enctype="multipart/form-data"`, like this: `<form id="form1" enctype="multipart/form-data" runat="server">`